Can't use the resource file
Here are my steps to add a file to resources:
Step 1

Step 2

Step 3

Then this file appeared in my solution explorer:

But I can't use it using Properties.Resources:

If I add the file to the resources using the BackgroundImage property in the Form, I can use it. But I can't add the ani file to the resources this way.

To use cursor you either need to construct it or extract it. Any reason to pack 1.ani into resources and not marking that file itself as embedded resource? I wonder if the problem is simply type "File" and I guess for background image it was some sort of image, therefore property with proper type was generated, but in case of "File"-type, what should be the type of property?

I solved my problem in a strange way. I clicked on the cursor name (Step 3) with the right mouse button, clicked on the repeating resource. I got cursor1, and in the resources there was cursor : byte[] and cursor1 : byte[] (fourth picture). Now I can delete cursor1 and use Properties.Resources.cursor

I solved my problem in a strange way. I clicked on the cursor name (Step 3) with the right mouse button, then clicked on the repeating resource. I got cursor1, and in the resources there was cursor : byte[] and cursor1 : byte[] (fourth picture). Now I can delete cursor1 and use Properties.Resources.cursor.
